# The animal's pearl

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Found in the gut of the creatures of the earth,
Polished till it shines, then it proves its worth,
Believed by philosophers to neutralise poison,
The antidote to arsenic via chemical reaction,
A mysterious gem, locked in the girth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer must be

> A Bezoar. Found in a goat if I remember correctly. The rest just fall into places. Thanks to *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*.

**Found in the gut of the creatures of the earth**

> According to the stories it is found in the gut of a goat aka creature of the earth.

**Polished till it shines...**

> Again according to the stories it needs to be "processed". Come on it comes from the gut of a goat, you gotta clean it first.

**..to neutralise poison**

> That is what a bezoar does. And the rest are just repetitions

Comment: Well done on solving the riddle! Also, I haven't ready Harry Potter, but I know what a bezoar is!

Comment: @Randal'Thor Done :)
Although I need help in editing. It just can't seem to make separate paragraphs in the spoiler quote

Comment: @RohitJose Thanks! I just remember it because it is where I first came across the term. Also please accept the answer and mark it as solved :)

Comment: I fixed the spoilertags for you :-) Alternatively, you can put a double space at the end of each line to get separate paragraphs inside a spoilerblock.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is describing

> a [bezoar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezoar).

Comment: RD just beat you to it :-)

Comment: So I see: by 76 seconds. I shouldn't have bothered looking up the Wikipedia link :-).

Comment: Well done, but a minute too late